# What is the job of "RepeatVector" and "TimeDistributed"?

Tags: keras, lstm

I read about them in Keras documentation and other websites, but I couldn't exactly understand what exactly they do and how should we use them in designing `many-to-many` or `encoder-decoder` LSTM networks?

I saw them used in the solution of [this problem here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6063).

> ```
> model = Sequential()  
> model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=False))  
> model.add(RepeatVector(10))
> model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_neurons, return_sequences=True))  
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
> model.add(Activation('linear'))   
> model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
> ```

Comment: Here in this example, `RepeatVector()` is taking the output of the first LSTM and repeats it 10 times. That gives the second LSTM a sequences of lenght=10. But I don't get the intuition behind repeating a vector before giving it to another LSTM ?

Comment: found a good tutorial that explains everything about encoder-decoder architecture including `RepeatVector()` and `TimeDistributed()` here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-long-short-term-memory-networks/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RepeatVector)**

According to the docs :

> Repeats the input n times.

They have also provided an example :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=32))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 32)
# note: `None` is the batch dimension
model.add(RepeatVector(3))
# now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 32)
```

In the above example, the `RepeatVector` layer repeats the incoming inputs a specific number of time. The shape of the input in the above example was `( 32 , )`. But the output shape of the `RepeatVector` was `( 3 , 32 )`, since the inputs were repeated 3 times.

**[tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed)**

According to the docs :

> This wrapper allows to apply a layer to every temporal slice of an input.
>   The input should be at least 3D, and the dimension of index one will be considered to be the temporal dimension.

You can refer to the example at their website.

`TimeDistributed` layer applies a specific layer such as `Dense` to every sample it receives as an input. Suppose the input size is ( 13 , 10 , 6 ). Now, I need to apply a Dense layer to every slice of shape ( 10 , 6 ). Then I would wrap the `Dense` layer in a `TimeDistributed` layer.

```
model.add( TimeDistributed( Dense( 12 , input_shape=( 10 , 6 ) )) )
```

The output shape of such a layer would be ( 13 , 10 , 12 ). Hence, the operation of the `Dense` layer was applied to each temporal slice as mentioned.

Comment: and when should they be used?

Comment: @Shubham I think that the question is about "why" are they using `RepeatVector()` and not just one LSTM with return_sequence=True. I don't get the intuition behind repeating the output of the first LSTM and feeding it to the second one.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the OP was asking about these layers in a practical sense (he mentioned autoencoders and sequence to sequence), which you didn't address. Can you clarify your answer to include the WHY they'd be used in these contexts? It's pretty obvious what RepeatVector() does, but why would you want to use it for a encoder-decoder model?

Answer (score 10):

For encoder-decoder, your input is squashed into a single feature vector, if you want your output to regenerate the same dimension as the original input, you are "artificially" converting this feature tensor from 1D into 2D by replicating it using `RepeatVector()`.

Comment: this was the answer I was looking for